# NPM get prefix issues

Tags: node.js, npm, angular-cli

I am having issues with the npm. (on MAC)
I installed node and npm normally, but couldn't run:
$npm install -g angular-cli

it says unhandled rejection error, EACCESS: ...

and none of the solutions I found on the web couldn't help me.

I tried to reinstall node and npm multiple times, didn't help.

Then I tried to make an ionic project through the terminal, unsuccessfully. Similar issue EACCESS: permission denied...

And now I kind of messed up something with:
$npm config get prefix and $npm config set prefix

whenever I try to run some npm command I get a bunch of lines:

Eaccess, cannot read property, etc...

Does anybody know how can I solve this?
Is there a way to completely remove nodejs and npm and then to install it from scratch.

The traditional way and using homebrew didn't help me.

Comment: Could you copy and post a snapshot of the error (s).

Comment: Here are screenshots of the error(s):

https://ibb.co/NYJfYCx
https://ibb.co/ZWFCxvc
https://ibb.co/zJV53yz

Answer (score 0):

Try: nvm uninstall {version of node you are using}

To get the version do: npm -version

Comment: nvm command not found, and with npm uninstall I get the same error I get with npm config. :(